# PHP simple_load_file and file_get_content with email and password

Tags: php, xml, email, passwords

I'd like to get password protected xml file in my script via url like:

```
account@domain.com:password@domain2.com/file.xml
```

I found working in web browser version (just type in browser and xml appear with no redirection or password prompt) of url:

```
account%40domain.com:password@domain2.com/file.xml
```

So I try use this url with simple_load_file() and file_get_contents(), but it did not work (I know this functions need urlencode due to special character in url but `account%40domain.com:password%40domain2.com/file.xml` does not work).

So I try another solution found on stackoverlow:

```
$username = 'account@domain.com';
$password = 'password';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents('domain2.com/file.xml', false, $context);
```

And I get error:

```
...failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...
```

I also try curl, no success too (returned code 302). I'm out of idea to fix this problem. Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: 302 is a redirection code, you are supposed to read the suggested URL from the server response and perform a new request to that location to get the contents.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` will follow redirects (e.g. 302) automatically, but you do need to tell it that you're fetching a remote file, by providing the scheme. Change

```
$data = file_get_contents('domain2.com/file.xml', false, $context);
```

to

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://domain2.com/file.xml', false, $context);
```

(or **https://** if appropriate)

If you don't provide the scheme, it will try to open a file on the local machine - i.e. a file called `file.xml` under the directory `domain2.com`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You were right, but now I have another error:`...failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in..`.

Comment: That sounds more like an issue with the remote file than the code. Without knowing the actual URL it's impossible to say, though.

Comment: Can I send you actual url via private massage?